# PHP Undefined Index (WP Customer Area breaks on file download)

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined, warnings

The company I work for are using Customer Area for one of our clients and everything has been great until recently. When a private file is tried to be downloaded we get several error messages appear:

```
Notice: Undefined index: force-download in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php on line 1029

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 945

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 952

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 955

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 956

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 959

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 960

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 961

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php:1029) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-default-handlers.class.php on line 989
```

When trying to reset the plugin settings or database through the plugin we also get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cuar_admin_theme_url in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-classes/settings.class.php on line 674

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-classes/settings.class.php:674) in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

We are using our own WordPress theme which we have removed all customised WP Customer Area templates, and even switched themes to TwentySeventeen but the errors still appear. As well as switching themes we have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin.

So we decided to create a new blank WordPress environment and test it there and re-download the plugin so it is new. The download button then began to work but when testing for a second/third time the errors returned.

As previously mentioned the plugin was working perfectly up until being discovered yesterday. We haven’t edited any of the core files only the template files which we did by following the instructions of WP Customer Area. The site is running WordPress 4.9.1 and plugin version is 7.4.5. However, we have tried with Wordpress 4.9 and plugin versions 7.4.0, 7.3.0.

If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read my message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the people at WP Customer Area and they are looking into the issue as it seems to be a bug in the plugin. But in the meantime they have given me some code to stop the errors by replacing:

```
!isset($_GET['force-download']) && $_GET['force-download'] != 1)
```

On line 1029 in customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php.

with the line:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['force-download']) || (isset($_GET['force-download']) && $_GET['force-download'] !== 1))
```

This has helped me with the errors and hope it helps you guys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will probably need to chase this bug through a lot of code, but the general fix is to identify situations where an array key is assumed to be existing and fix it with some code.

The error tells you where to start:

`Notice: Undefined index: force-download in /Users/mathew/Websites/mamp/portal-test/wp-content/plugins/customer-area/src/php/core-addons/private-file/private-file-addon.class.php on line 1029`

From the index name, `force-download` I would guess this is the value of a checkbox on an HTML form.  When unchecked, no value is passed via HTTP POST yet the script is looking for this in $_POST (guessing here).

The best advice I can give is to fix the instances of this with something like:

```
<?PHP

if( array_key_exists( 'force-download', $_POST ) && $_POST['force-download'] )
{
    // do something
}

?>
```

---

**What I do for my forms:**

In order to always have a $_POST value, I output a hidden form field with a zero value *before* the checkbox field.  Then the checkbox field has a value of 1. That way the checkbox field, if checked, passes '1' via $_POST and my `if` statements just work without having to always be constantly be checking for empty, array_key_exists, etc.

Comment: Hi @TimG thanks for commenting, it's really appreciated. That's a good tip about the forms though I will keep it in mind.